# Зависание GUI при изменении QProgressBar из QThread с помощью сигналов

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Зависает GUI при изменении QProgressBar из QThread с помощью сигналов.

Код:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QThread>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
~Widget();

public slots:

private slots:
void on_pushButton_1_clicked();

private:
Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H


#include "widget.h"
#include "worker.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_1_clicked()
{
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
                this,
                "Открыть файл",
                "",
                "Все файлы (*.*)",
                nullptr,
                QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog
                );
if (filename != QString("")) {
    ui->label_2->setText(filename);
    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    Worker *worker = new Worker(filename);
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::process);
    connect(worker, &Worker::finished, thread, &QThread::quit);
    connect(worker, &Worker::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QObject::deleteLater);

    connect(worker, &Worker::progressRangeChanged, ui->progressBar, &QProgressBar::setRange);
    connect(worker, &Worker::progressValueChanged, ui->progressBar, &QProgressBar::setValue);

    thread->start();
}
}

#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
QString workerFilename;

public:
explicit Worker(QString filename, QObject *parent = nullptr);
virtual ~Worker();

signals:
void finished();
void error(QString err);
void progressRangeChanged(int min,int max);
void progressValueChanged(int progress);

public slots:
void process();
};

#endif // WORKER_H

#include "worker.h"

Worker::Worker(QString filename, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
workerFilename = filename;
}

Worker::~Worker()
{

}

void Worker::process()
{
//    qDebug()<<workerFilename;
QFile file(workerFilename);
int fileSize = file.size();
emit progressRangeChanged(0, fileSize);
for (int i = 0; i <= fileSize; i++) {
    emit progressValueChanged(i);
}
emit finished();
}
```

QProgressBar обновляется. GUI виджета зависают, окно нельзя переместить.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: Вы посылаете кучу сигналов в цикле, что забивает очередь сообщений, поэтому, скорее всего, Вы и видите зависание.

Comment: У цикла нет явных ограничений, поэтому он на всю мощь процессора начал выполнять его, самое простое -- добавьте задержку после `emit progressValueChanged(i);` в 1 мс и проверьте

Comment: С задержкой работает.

Comment: Только как-то медленно. Видимо, надо будет придумать как делать задержку не в каждой итерации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта задача достаточно типичная. Давайте представим, что в файле миллион строк (а иначе зачем вообще нужно было бы отображать прогресс?) И на каждую строку будет делать обновление прогресса (что бы пользователь его видел). Самые ходовые мониторы сейчас - это fullhd и им подобные, которые имеют 1920 точек по ширине. Так как полоса прогресса вряд ли будет занимать весь экран, я думаю, 1000 пикселей удобное число и вполне реальное для ширины самого прогресса.

А теперь вопрос. Увидит ли пользователь разницу между 9000 и 9500 итеррацией цикла? Нет, не увидит. Потому что обе будут занимать 9 (или 10) пикселей ширины полосы. Если посидеть помедитировать, то станет ясно, что обновлять чаще, чем раз в 1000 итерраций нет смысла (1000 это 1000000 строк файле на 1000 пикселей ширины экрана).

По собственному опыту скажу, что на самом деле можно обновлять раз в 5-10 пикселей и пользователь будет счастлив.

Как это исправить самым простым способом?

Вместо

```
emit progressValueChanged(i);
```

написать строку вот так

```
if (i % 1000 == 0) {
  emit progressValueChanged(i);
}
```

вместо 1000 лучше подставить свою константу, которая должна быть не меньше, чем fileSize деленный на ширину прогресса (а оптимально - ещё и умножить на 5-10).

И самое главное, не забыть в самом конце добавить строку, которая подвинет прогресс в самый конец (на 100%). А то тут как повезет (если кол-во записей будет кратно 1000, то добежит, а иначе нет).

Comment: Спасибо! Код поправлю.